# Converting PSD file to JPG using graphic magick

Tags: graphicsmagick

I 'm trying to convert psd file  to jpg format file by using following commands:

```
gm -convert [input file name].psd -colorspace rgb -resize 150x150  -strip -quality 92 -   sharpen 2  [output file name].jpg

gm -convert -clip -negate  [input file name].psd -thumbnail 150x150     [output file name].jpg
```

Both the commands are working fine.But for some psd file having rgb colorspace  it **does not** generate correct rendition.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `ImageMagick`？ `ImageMagick` has the same *command-line*, but also have a thumbnail of PSD, get by this:

```
convert a.psd[0] b.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

The PSD reader in GraphicsMagick is not very robust and PSD is very complex and poorly documented.  The best free implementation I have seen is in The GIMP.

Answer (score 0):

I have just created a Node module that deals with PSD files from the CLI.

For all non-Windows users out there that don't want to crack Photoshop just to see a proper rendered file (Gimp is not really a solution and has a poor understanding of modern PSD files).

Instructions from the [Github repo](https://github.com/kartsims/psd-cli) :

Install it :

`npm install -g psd-cli`

Convert `myfile.psd` to a new `myfile.png` :

`psd myfile.psd`

Hope you find this useful ! Any feature requests is most enjoyed, I have a ton in mind and help with improving the code is appreciated :)